# How to store and reuse cookies in Postman?

Tags: cookies, httprequest, session-cookies, postman

I'm using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test and play with an API.

For the login url, the API requires sending a POST request with `username` and `password` as fields. I do this, and I get a `200` response with the message that I am logged in.

I then try another request to get user data. However, I get a response that I am not logged in.

I realized this problem is most likely because the cookie that is sent to me when I log in is not included in the next Postman request.

So my question is, how do I save and include cookies for future requests?

Comment: @CodyBugstien , Did you manage to solve this issue , same problem is happening to me

Answer (score 10):

Store the cookie value you want to use in a global variable.In `Tests` tab of login request, write

```
postman.setGlobalVariable('key', postman.getResponseCookie("cookieName").value);
```

Pass along with the value in the `Headers` tab as a cookie in get user request:

```
Cookie | cookieName={{key}}
```

Comment: I believe this may be outdated code?  It produces a null reference error now it seems.

Answer (score 4):

I tried using Ashutosh's answer but got an error. I'm guessing this is because Postman's scripting API changed?

At any rate, the following worked for me:

1. In the `Tests` tab of the request that will return cookies you want to save, write

```
pm.globals.set('<your key>', pm.cookies.get('<cookie name>'));
```

2. Then, as described in Ashutosh's answer, add the cookie to the headers by setting the key as `cookie` and corresponding value as `<your cookie name>={{<global variable name>}};`.

I found documentation for this at the [Postman sandbox API reference](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference/).

Answer (score 3):

(Using the native Postman app without the interceptor)
The traditional way of reading the cookie does not work for me `pm.cookies.get('<cookie name>')`
. Here is a workaround that automatically attaches auth cookie to all requests within a collection:

```
// The test scripts below run after the api /login returns the response

const authCookie = pm.response.headers.idx(3).value
/* 
pm.response.headers.idx(3) is equal to:
{key: "Set-Cookie", value: "xs=eyJhb; Max-Age=3600; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 18 Dec 2020 04:40:34 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None"} 
*/

const token = authCookie.substring(3, authCookie.indexOf(';'))
pm.collectionVariables.set('xs_value', token);
```

Then add this pre-request scripts to the entire collection:

```
// Scripts below runs before any request within a collection is sent

const token = pm.collectionVariables.get('xs_value')
pm.request.headers.upsert({ key: 'Cookie', value: `xs=${token}` })
```

Enjoy!

More info on how to [attach headers to requests](https://community.postman.com/t/setting-headers-for-entire-collection-folder/708/14)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are two Interceptor plugin in google chrome. make sure install the [correct one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo).