# How do I capture https requests with Postman native app using Windows 10?

Tags: https, proxy, windows-10, postman

I am using the Postman native app on Windows 10 and am struggling with trying to capture https requests. [Postman's Documentation](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/capture_native) for this is for Mac and not Windows.

In particular, I am working on a web application that creates a session cookie upon login that needs to be included in most requests in order to be authorized. When I was using the Chrome App, Postman Interceptor achieved this (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32436131/3816779).

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Turn on the Proxy in Postman with port 5555.
           [image: Postman proxy configuration]
2. Configured windows to send http and https requests through Postman's proxy server (127.0.0.1:5555).
           [image: Windows proxy configuration]

This allows http requests to be captured in Postman
[image: Http requests captured in History Tab]

But when trying to connect to https sites, I get an error
[image: Error with https connection in Chrome]

Here are my Postman settings if that helps.
[image: Postman general settings] [image: Postman certificates settings]

**Update** I ended up switching back to the Chrome App, which uses the "Interceptor" instead of a "Proxy Server" to capture traffic.

Comment: Same issue and now switching back to chrome app. that is really frustrating

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find any useful responses without going back to the chrome plugin?

Comment: gaudi_br Try Lukáš Kmoch's EDIT. It seems to fix the problem, but I'm a couple years away from it so not entirely sure.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, capture https requests with postman native app is impossible in some case according to the official doc: [Capturing HTTP requests](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/capturing_http_requests)

> Note: for the Postman native apps, request captures over HTTPS will not work if the website has HSTS enabled. Most websites have this check in place.

Answer (score 4):

Postman's proxy now supports HTTPS traffic - https://blog.postman.com/postmans-proxy-now-fully-supports-https-endpoints/

Once you install a CA certificate that Postman generates for your installation, capturing HTTPS requests should be seamless.

Disclaimer: I work at Postman

Answer (score 2):

With Google Chrome i don't know how to fix the issue. But you can use to open the web page for example IE..

EDIT:
Or MAYBE you can start Google Chrome with parameter --ignore-certificate-errors to ignore the error message.

Comment: The question's referring to the native app in Windows, as opposed to the chrome app. Haven't used postman for this in a while, so not sure if this is still an issue with the current version.

Comment: It is still an issue, I tried it few weeks ago. And i know the question is referring to the native app but with nativ app you still need to use web browser to open the page and the issue is only with Google Chrome

Comment: Oops, I misinterpreted your answer. Starting Chrome with --ignore-certificate-errors prevented the error messages from showing up, and the requests appeared in Postman history.

If running chrome with arguments is new to you like it was for me, here's some instructions https://pastebin.com/raw/MDT1RbF2, quoted from here https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-bypass-your-connection-is-not-private-message.

Answer (score 1):

[Postman Interceptor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en) is available for Postman native apps which supports both features:

*1. Capturing requests* 
*2. Syncing cookies*

Learn more [here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/interceptor/).

Comment: I think maybe you should add a disclaimer that you work there. This could add even more credibility.

Comment: @Vinit when using Interceptor I am getting 401 on pages which requires authentication

Answer (score -1):

Just check HTTPS in setting and will work for you

[image]

Comment: It looks like that tab is a new feature that addresses the problem, awesome. I frankly don't feel like putting in the effort to test out this solution though (I no longer need to use that part of postman), so I'll unnaccept the accepted answer and let the crowd take over from here.

Comment: That is if you are in a proxy network... no for config the postman as proxy.

Comment: This setting is for using Postman _behind a proxy_ **not to** configure Postman as Proxy to intercept requests.