# { "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect." }

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman, django-csrf, csrf-token

[image]

hello guys . I try to register a new Product in my app using DRF and Postman.
when I send a request I get this error.
the problem is just about my csrf_token.
I'll be thankfull if you help me.....

this is my view

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,TokenAuthentication) 
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    queryset = ProductInfo.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ['title','code','owner__username']
```

I don't have any problem for GET request.

Comment: `GET` is working because it doesnt need csrf. Do you need session authentication for this view at all? If yes, how did you get your csrf token?

Comment: yes, if I don't use it I cant send get request.

Comment: what should I add in postman header?

Comment: Where did you get the csrf token?

Comment: in the postman header (Cookie) header I got it

Comment: Enable [Postman Interceptor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en) ... [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46994304/14131913)

Comment: thanks for your solution, I activated it but it doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

Django requires CSRF token in `POST` request by default. to avoid CSRF tokens.

Don't use `SessionAuthentication` as authentication class, coz, it will force you to add CSRF token.

If you still want to use `SessionAuthentication` then You can use it overrideing

`def enforce_csrf(self, request):` method

Try below this:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication

class CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication(SessionAuthentication):
    def enforce_csrf(self, request):
        pass
```

and use it in your views:

```
authentication_classes = (CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication ,TokenAuthentication)
```

If you want to use it globally, you can place it in your REST_FRAMEWORK settings.py file like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'myapp.path-to-file.CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication'
    ],
}
```

Please make sure you add correct file path in the REST_FRAMEWORK settings

To authenticate with the token.

You must request like this:

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/example/ -H 'Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b'
```

Also make sure you added this in your INSTALLED_APP:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ''''
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]
```

More details can be found here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

Comment: when I don't use it I get an `{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}`

Comment: Coz, you have not added token

Comment: I have no idea what should I do now

Comment: i've added the autherization and bearer token

Comment: Wait, i am updating the answer more deeply

Comment: I have updated the answer with more details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235251/discussion-between-anamul-and-abolfazl81).

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't need `csrf_token` for `GET` method.

you can set your `csrf_token` in header like this:

```
X-CSRFToken: your_csrf_value
```

so instead of using `Cookie` add `X-CSRFToken` to your header in POSTMAN.