# How to access drf(django rest framework) api in local network from different machine?

Tags: python, django, apache, django-rest-framework, deployment

I deployed a drf api in apache server , when i access it from the same machine it work fine (get and post requests and also database connections all works good) , but when I try it from another machine in the same network i got two errors specially if it's a post request or there is a connection with database , the first one before sending anything it said

> "HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"

and if I try to send post requests it said

> "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."

and also if there is a get request has connections to database i got 500 server error .
I tried to follow the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/) and also looked for these questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639169/csrf-failed-csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68507396/detail-csrf-failed-csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect) but didn't help , actually I'm not even sure what cause these problems .
*Note* : when i try just runserver command it works fine from other machines .
here is virtual host and settings.py .
virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.100.102:8001 _default_:8001>
    
    DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/team_city/myproject/myproject
    ServerAdmin yaz@gmail.com
     

    # Set the path to your Django project
    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/env/ python-path=/opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/team_city/myproject/myproject
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/team_city/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py

    # Configure access to static files
    Alias /static/ /opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/team_city/myproject/static
    <Directory /opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/team_city/myproject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/team_city/myproject/myproject>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/logs/drfapp_error.log
    CustomLog /opt/bitnami/projects/chatbotQZ/sources/logs/drfapp_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

settings.py :

```
"""
Django settings for myproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.18.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-=z(3%l&3lrwvz16411c!-kjqaeb#@644o4$cd&go!w0ymi6(30'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False


#ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.100.102']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'base',
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'base.user_auth'
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'chatbot',
        'USER': 'dev',
        'PASSWORD': 'wXNjZWoJmBB5',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Comment: Please turn debug to true to see better error logging.

Comment: @Drizzle I can't when I put it in apache for deployment I can't put Debug True ,if I try I got error say something like "this is because you put debug True"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main problem was csrf token , when I used postman and disabled cookies and send csrf token in header it worked , but even tho I decide to remove it , by deleting 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication' from rest-framework/settings.py and it's work fine .

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons you might be experiencing this. I’ll go over a few of those.

1. Be sure the ip `'192.168.100.102'` is the ip of the machine currently hosting your application.
2. Make sure the machine your application is on can communicate with the machine your database is hosted on. If they are on the same machine then they probably shouldn’t be having any issues.
3. Ensure that CORS policy for your application is properly set to accept requests from other origins.

Comment: for 1. yes I am sure , when I test it with runserver command I can access it from other machine ,, for 2. they are both at same machine and they do communicate fine in test . but I guess my actual problem is crsf token in authentication , i saw some questions in SO but didn't understand well how it could help me .